# Showing a "what's this?" message when a UITableViewController is blank

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

My app contains several UITableViewControllers which don't necessarily have content in all circumstances. For example, a Drafts screen is empty if the user doesn't have any drafts.

In cases like that, I'd like to show a brief message explaining what the screen is for, something like this screen from the built-in Photos app:

[image: An iOS navigation bar over a blank screen containing the outlines of two photos, followed by the caption "No Photos or Videos", then the text "You can take photos or videos using the camera, sync photos or videos onto your iPhone using iTunes, or add photos and videos from other albums and events."]

What is the best way to get a descriptive view on screen? I can't subclass UIViewController directly, as I'm depending on some iOS 6 functionality that's tied specifically to UITableViewController, so as far as I can tell, I have to display this view inside a UITableView. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Subclass `UITableViewController`, and then in `-viewDidAppear:` or some other similarly appropriate place, check if the number of cells in the table will be zero. If so, add this overlay; if not, ensure the overlay is removed. Sample code below:

```
@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController
...
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIImageView *informativeOverlayImageView;
...
@end

@implementation MyTableViewController

...

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Just for an example - you'll have your own logic for determining if there will be zero rows.
    if (self.myDataModel.items.count == 0 &&
        !self.informativeOverlayImageView.superview)
    {
        if (!self.informativeOverlayImageView)
        {
            self.informativeOverlayImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initwithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImageName"]];
            [self.informativeOverlayImageView sizeToFit];
        }
        [self.view addSubview:self.informativeOverlayImageView];
    }
    else if (self.myDataModel.items.count > 0 &&
            self.informativeOverlayImageView.superview)
    {
        [self.informativeOverlayImageView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.tableView reloadData]; // Add animations to taste.
    }
}

...

@end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you'll also need to disable scrolling.